# Memcached: Keys being deleted after specific number of items inserted

Tags: memcached

I'm debugging a php script which is saving data in `memcache` as a way to warmup an application.
This script only makes `set` calls to save data into `memcache`, and after a specific number of entries being set, the first items inserted start to disappear (behaviour reproducible).

I've been reading memcache documentation, and learnt about the **eviction** process so started to check logs and read the stats to see if that's the reason.

Stopping the php script just before inserting the item that starts erasing the first elements, I run `stats slabs`:

```
stats slabs
STAT 1:chunk_size 96
STAT 1:chunks_per_page 10922
STAT 1:total_pages 1
STAT 1:total_chunks 10922
STAT 1:used_chunks 1
STAT 1:free_chunks 10921
STAT 1:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 1:mem_requested 93
STAT 1:get_hits 0
STAT 1:cmd_set 1
STAT 1:delete_hits 0
STAT 1:incr_hits 0
STAT 1:decr_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_badval 0
STAT 1:touch_hits 0
STAT 3:chunk_size 152
STAT 3:chunks_per_page 6898
STAT 3:total_pages 4
STAT 3:total_chunks 27592
STAT 3:used_chunks 22787
STAT 3:free_chunks 4805
STAT 3:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 3:mem_requested 3232040
STAT 3:get_hits 0
STAT 3:cmd_set 22814
STAT 3:delete_hits 0
STAT 3:incr_hits 0
STAT 3:decr_hits 0
STAT 3:cas_hits 0
STAT 3:cas_badval 0
STAT 3:touch_hits 0
STAT 4:chunk_size 192
STAT 4:chunks_per_page 5461
STAT 4:total_pages 1
STAT 4:total_chunks 5461
STAT 4:used_chunks 1300
STAT 4:free_chunks 4161
STAT 4:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 4:mem_requested 202877
STAT 4:get_hits 0
STAT 4:cmd_set 1301
STAT 4:delete_hits 0
STAT 4:incr_hits 0
STAT 4:decr_hits 0
STAT 4:cas_hits 0
STAT 4:cas_badval 0
STAT 4:touch_hits 0
STAT active_slabs 3
STAT total_malloced 6291008
```

As you can see, all slabs still have free space left.

When letting the script insert the next item, memcache server logs this:

```
30: going from conn_closing to conn_closed
29: going from conn_read to conn_parse_cmd
<29 set [tc:e-401:id-2485:profile-5:property-11][1] 0 0 3
29: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
> NOT FOUND [tc:e-401:id-2485:profile-5:property-11][1]
>29 STORED
```

Calling again `stats slabs` I see that a new slab has been used:

```
stats slabs
STAT 1:chunk_size 96
STAT 1:chunks_per_page 10922
STAT 1:total_pages 1
STAT 1:total_chunks 10922
STAT 1:used_chunks 1
STAT 1:free_chunks 10921
STAT 1:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 1:mem_requested 93
STAT 1:get_hits 0
STAT 1:cmd_set 1
STAT 1:delete_hits 0
STAT 1:incr_hits 0
STAT 1:decr_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_badval 0
STAT 1:touch_hits 0
STAT 2:chunk_size 120
STAT 2:chunks_per_page 8738
STAT 2:total_pages 1
STAT 2:total_chunks 8738
STAT 2:used_chunks 1
STAT 2:free_chunks 8737
STAT 2:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 2:mem_requested 120
STAT 2:get_hits 0
STAT 2:cmd_set 1
STAT 2:delete_hits 0
STAT 2:incr_hits 0
STAT 2:decr_hits 0
STAT 2:cas_hits 0
STAT 2:cas_badval 0
STAT 2:touch_hits 0
STAT 3:chunk_size 152
STAT 3:chunks_per_page 6898
STAT 3:total_pages 4
STAT 3:total_chunks 27592
STAT 3:used_chunks 22790
STAT 3:free_chunks 4802
STAT 3:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 3:mem_requested 3232437
STAT 3:get_hits 0
STAT 3:cmd_set 22817
STAT 3:delete_hits 0
STAT 3:incr_hits 0
STAT 3:decr_hits 0
STAT 3:cas_hits 0
STAT 3:cas_badval 0
STAT 3:touch_hits 0
STAT 4:chunk_size 192
STAT 4:chunks_per_page 5461
STAT 4:total_pages 1
STAT 4:total_chunks 5461
STAT 4:used_chunks 1300
STAT 4:free_chunks 4161
STAT 4:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 4:mem_requested 202877
STAT 4:get_hits 0
STAT 4:cmd_set 1301
STAT 4:delete_hits 0
STAT 4:incr_hits 0
STAT 4:decr_hits 0
STAT 4:cas_hits 0
STAT 4:cas_badval 0
STAT 4:touch_hits 0
STAT active_slabs 4
STAT total_malloced 7339568
END
```

The first item (with key starting with "`tc:e-501`" is no longer present (checked using `memdump --servers=localhost | grep tc:e-501`, and calling a `get` from php to get the first key also gives me non-existing)

Calling `stats items` I see that the evictions counter is 0...

```
stats items
STAT items:1:number 1
STAT items:1:age 1391
STAT items:1:evicted 0
STAT items:1:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:1:evicted_time 0
STAT items:1:outofmemory 0
STAT items:1:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:1:reclaimed 0
STAT items:1:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:1:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:1:crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT items:2:number 1
STAT items:2:age 982
STAT items:2:evicted 0
STAT items:2:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:2:evicted_time 0
STAT items:2:outofmemory 0
STAT items:2:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:2:reclaimed 0
STAT items:2:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:2:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:2:crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT items:3:number 22790
STAT items:3:age 1391
STAT items:3:evicted 0
STAT items:3:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:3:evicted_time 0
STAT items:3:outofmemory 0
STAT items:3:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:3:reclaimed 0
STAT items:3:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:3:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:3:crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT items:4:number 1300
STAT items:4:age 1381
STAT items:4:evicted 0
STAT items:4:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:4:evicted_time 0
STAT items:4:outofmemory 0
STAT items:4:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:4:reclaimed 0
STAT items:4:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:4:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:4:crawler_reclaimed 0
END
```

Following calls to `set` from the script keep removing the first items inserted sequentially, so I discard a key collision.

What may be causing this behaviour? I'm currently completely clueless.

*Edited:* Using memcached 1.4.20
*Edited:* Using option `-M` does not seems to help, items still get removed and no `set` call return any `false` value.

Comment: Just a quick question, after how many sets does this behavior occur ? if so is the data size of the set in the limits ? can you check parameter -I (I in India) in /etc/memcached.conf or where your memcached config is.

Comment: Currently, after 24115 `set` calls it starts removing items. About the `-I`, I'm on osx, installed it through `brew` and to set any configuration I need to put it as an argument. Currently I'm not setting it so using the default value.

Comment: Can you start memcached using the following command and  test it ? `memcached -p 11211 -d -u root -I 8m  -m 256 -vvv  >> /var/log/memcached 2&1`. This command starts memcached with max item size 8MB with 256MB memory. I may think the problem may be item size. Also check memcached log or remove it to see debug. Thanks

Comment: Tried, and no changes :(

Comment: Damn, i was hoping a change, as a last recommendation, would it be problematic if you use an older/newer version ? perhaps an internal bug ?

Comment: The only special thing happening here is that an object of a specific size which hasn't appeared before is inserted here. This new object size  requires a new slab allocation with this specific chunk size. What is your exact memcached configuration?